# Creating a New Column in Existing HTML Table using DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

Attempting to create a new column within an existing table using DOMDocument and DOMXpath

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("example.html");
```

Here is how the table located in `example.html` is structured:

```
<table id="transactions" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="image"></th>
            <th class="title"><span>Title</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tbody-tr">
            <td class="image">
                <img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
            </td>
            <td class="title">Title
            </td>
            <td class="date">12/16/2017
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tbody-tr">
            <td class="image">
                <img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
            </td>
            <td class="title">Title
            </td>
            <td class="date">12/16/2017
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this case, the xpath query for the table would be

```
$table =  $xpath->query('//*[@id="transactions"]');
```

For the `<tr id="tbody-tr">` element

```
$tr = $xpath->query('/*[@id="tbody-tr"]');
```

And for the `<td>` row elements -- /td[1] /td[2] /td[3]

```
$td = $xpath->query('//*[@id="tbody-tr"]/td[3]');
```

I'm trying to create an additional column (`<td class="example"></td>`) in between `<td class="title">` and `<td class="date">` for all instances of `<tr id="tbody-tr">` (there are about 50, but minified for the sake of the question).

I'm new to DOMDocument and HTML Parsing Manipulation, and am having a hell of a time trying to figure out how to do this.

I'm assuming I'll either have to loop it using my `xpath->query`, something like

```
foreach ($ttrows as $row) {
    $td = $doc->createElement('td');
    $parent = $row->parentNode;
    $parent->appendChild($row);
    $td->setAttribute('class','example');
}
```

or use DOMDocuments `getElementById` or something similar.

```
foreach ($table = $doc->getElementById('tbody-tr') as $table) {
    $td = $doc->createElement('td');
    $td->setAttribute('class', 'example');
    $td->appendChild($table);
    $table->insertBefore($td, $table);
}
```

As I said, I am new to DOMDocument, so both of those examples do practically nothing.. but I think I am heading in the right direction (I hope).

The table, I believe, is fairly well structured to do something like this in DOMDocument. Can someone please shed some light on this, my trials and errors are leaving me with little result.

Solution:

```
foreach ($td as $row) {
    $td = $doc->createElement('td', 'text to be inserted');
    $td->setAttribute('class','example');
    $row->parentNode->insertBefore($td, $row);
}
```

Note above that

```
$td = $xpath->query('//*[@id="tbody-tr"]/td[3]');
```

is the third `<td>` class `date`.

Comment: You are on the right track with `insertBefore`, but the `appendChild` wouldn't be needed. Just have to get the right reference on the second argument in `insertBefore`... which is the tricky part, as you have to ref that `<td class="date">`. Hmmmmm...

Comment: You are correct. I figured it out! See edit in a min.

Comment: Interesting solution. If I understand it correctly. ... but is it right to be matching on `id=`, and not `class=`? Anyhoo, @Lawrence's solution may be  better to use in the long run. Its a bit more predictable to follow and edit easily I would think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember you cant/shouldnt have multiple ids on the same page.

Then just use `$tr->insertBefore($td, $tr->childNodes->item(3));`

Which means, current node insert new dom node before 3rd td.

```
<?php
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr) {
    $td = $doc->createElement('td');
    $td->setAttribute('class', 'example');

    $tr->insertBefore($td, $tr->childNodes->item(3));
}
```

https://3v4l.org/TthE7

Also something to think about is to add the `thead > th` or it will break   the look of table.

```
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr) {

    // insert into thead > th
    if ($tr->childNodes->item(0)->nodeName == 'th') {
        $th = $doc->createElement('th');
        $th->setAttribute('class', 'example');
        $th->nodeValue = 'Example';
        $tr->insertBefore($th, $tr->childNodes->item(3));
    } 
    // insert into body > td
    else {
        $td = $doc->createElement('td');
        $td->setAttribute('class', 'example');

        $tr->insertBefore($td, $tr->childNodes->item(3));
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/1sj7s